# Dygraph not plotting graphs using csv link

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am not able to plot graph using dygraph with csv link.

If I use http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/ this link it works. When I replace data with link, it just shows empty graph. I tested in debugger tool and I do get proper response from file. If I just try to plot the graph using same data from file but adding the data in javascript as static content like the example provided in jsfiddle it works.

Things I tried - 
1. I tried .txt, .csv and file without extension and nothing worked
2. I tried on different data and when I insert data in static way in javascript it works. So data is in url is definitely not incorrect.
3. When checked response for url in debugger tool I get correct response

[image of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUEhy.png)

html code -

```
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Javascript -

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                 // For possible data formats, see http://dygraphs.com/data.html
                 "https://files.fm/down.php?i=8v88usam&n=testing_file_2.txt",
                 {
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are in the wrong format, see [Dygraphs Data Format](http://dygraphs.com/data.html)

> Here are some valid date formats for CSV:
>
> 2009-07-12
>
> 2009/07/12
>
> 2009/07/12 12
>
> 2009/07/12 12:34
>
> 2009/07/12 12:34:56

Comment: https://files.fm/down.php?i=cwj4pmg5&n=testing_file_2_(1).txt
This one does not contain dates and this one also does not work.

and I have tries those dates as I mentioned in description which works if you provide those dates and values as comma separated string and lines appennded with "\n" in your DyGraph object